# Flask-login AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'is_active'

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

Hello im trying to build db management site but when i try to login correctly it refers to AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'is_active' i already added UserMixin in my models.py but still the problem still persist.

App.py:

```
def config_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret'
    app.config['DEBUG'] = True
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "sqlite:///db/bogus.db"
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
    
    db.init_app(app)
    login_manager = LoginManager()
    login_manager.login_view = 'admin.index'
    login_manager.init_app(app)
    bootstrap = Bootstrap4(app)
    
    @login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user(user_id):
        return Admin.query.get(int(id))
    
    app.register_blueprint(find, url_prefix='/')
    app.register_blueprint(admin, url_prefix='/admin')
    app.register_blueprint(gateway, url_prefix='/api')
    return app
```

Routes.py

```
@admin.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    form = admin_login()
    return render_template('login.html', form=form)

@admin.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def index_post():
    form = admin_login()
    user = form.name.data
    password = form.password.data
    remember = form.remember.data
    user_check = Admin.query.filter_by(username=user).first()
    if user_check:
        password_check = check_password_hash(user_check.password, password)
        if password_check:
            login_user(user)
            return redirect(url_for('admin.search'))
```

Models.py

```
class Admin(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(80))
```

Error log

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vee/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2091, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/vee/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2076, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/vee/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/vee/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/vee/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/vee/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "/home/vee/beta-app/admin/routes.py", line 30, in index_post
    login_user(user)
  File "/home/vee/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_login/utils.py", line 166, in login_user
    if not force and not user.is_active:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'is_active'
```

Comment: On which line do you get this error?  I don't see a call to `is_active`.

Comment: In `login_user(user)`,  what do you mean `is_active` call? Thanks

Comment: Should it be `login(user_check)`?

Comment: Yes, sorry late reply,  I change it to `login(user_check)` and `user_id` instead of id to work.